# Clear then restore List in zedGraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I designed a real time graph application using zedGraph class `RollingPointPairList()`. User should be able to hide specific curve when `checkBox` is checked and show it when unchecked. 
The problem is that it never shows a curve again once it had been hidden. Actually, it should show curve with all points which were hide, but it draws straight line & drops specific points from list. How to do it correctly?

This is a sample code I'm using:

```
if (chkXScale.Checked == true) {
    zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList[0].Clear();
        zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i Guess by calling `zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList[0].Clear();` the data is removed so once you try to bring it back by checking the checkBox it finds no data to Draw !

i suggest that by the time you acquire data do 2 things:

1. Draw it in your zeGraph control `list.Add(x,y);`
2. Save the data for later use (in case you uncheck/check).

To save the data for late use you can choose any simple way you master, i just suggest using `Queue` As follows, so the whole operation becomes:

```
//declaration:
Queue<double> Xholder = new Queue<double>();
Queue<double> Yholder = new Queue<double>();
//when new data comes:
list.Add(x,y);
Xholder.Enqueue(x);
Yholder.Enqueue(y);

//when you uncheck then check the checkBox
for (int i=0; i<Xholder.Count; i++)
{
  list.Add(Xholder.Dequeue(), Yholder.Dequeue());
}
```

I hope that's all what you need, give me feedback when you try it